Как получить список диалогов с папки Телеграм в Telethon?
Нужное название получить могу, id папки. Как получить список диалогов с этой папки, или как сравнить есть ли этот диалог в этой папке?
    result = await client(GetDialogFiltersRequest())
    folders = result.filters
    folder_name = 'SP'
    folder_id = None
    if folders:
        for folder in folders:
            if isinstance(folder, DialogFilter):
                if folder.title == folder_name:
                    folder_id = folder.id
                print(folder.title)


Так работает (нужно было поспать):
# Получаем список папок
result = await client(GetDialogFiltersRequest())
folders = result.filters
folder_name = 'SP'
peer_ids = []

# Находим нужную папку по названию
if folders:
    for folder in folders:
        if isinstance(folder, DialogFilter):
            if folder.title == folder_name:
                print(folder)
                for peer in folder.include_peers:
                    if isinstance(peer, InputPeerChat):
                        peer_ids.append(peer.chat_id)
                    elif isinstance(peer, InputPeerChannel):
                        peer_ids.append(peer.channel_id)
                    elif isinstance(peer, InputPeerUser):
                        peer_ids.append(peer.user_id)
                print(peer_ids)

# Проверяем, что peer_ids не пустой
if peer_ids:
    await send_message_with_photo_to_groups(client, peer_ids)
else:
    print(f"Папка с названием '{folder_name}' не найдена или в ней нет включенных чатов.")

